# Run the same program in many processes

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, concurrency, process

#### Want

I would like to run the same program on many files.  I would like this to happen in several processes concurrently.

#### Example

I.e. given a program `foo` and data files `data1.dat`, `data2.dat`, `data3.dat` I want to write something like the following

```
$ map foo data{1,2,3}.dat
```

and have it be equivalent to the following

```
$ foo data1.dat & foo data2.dat & foo data3.dat
```

#### Question

Is this standard within the unix toolset?  If not then what is a simple bash script to accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in *.dat ; do foo "$i" & done
```

Comment: Maybe add "&" after "$i" since OP wants concurrency.

Comment: Can you verify that this works?  I tried the following `$ for i in * ; do ls "$i" & ; done` and received the following error `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'`

Comment: Yep, I knew `&` would function to terminate the command, but thought an "empty" command would work without needing further explanation. Clearly, I was wrong... Thanks, @that-other-guy, for fixing my second mistake.